# Cross referencing equation without 'equation' environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have many equations in a document. I used `\ [ \ ]` for start and end of a math equation. I labeled the equation with `\label{eq:1}`, referenced with `~\eqref{eq:1}`. It was showing just the section number. Can't we label and reference equations defined with `\ [` and `\ ]` and auto numbering enabled ? Is using 'equation' environment the only way ?
I needed equation to be numbered by (1) and (1) be displayed at `\eqref{eq:1}`.
Here's my code and output

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

% The graphicx package allows you to import JPG and PDF images
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=15mm,bmargin=30mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=20mm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LyX}    {L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\spacefactor1000}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{literature}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{equation}
   V^{m\times n}=G^{m\times3p}P^{3p\times n}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}   

Where `$m$' representing number of channels, `$n$' time samples considered, `$p$' number of dipoles considered. ~\eqref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if there is no equation number what text would you want `\ref` to make? if you don't want the automatic numbering sequence you can use the amsmath command `\tag` to supply any other label text which can then be used with label/ref

Comment: Equation numbering is done automatically by label number.. But with \ [ \ ] equations are not being numbered.

Comment: yes that is the only difference between `\[` and `\begin{equation}` you use `\[` if you do not want a number. what is your question?

Comment: Note that is a bad idea to use a number in the argument of `\label` such as `\label{eq;1}` it works but is confusing as the number is unrelated to any number that is printed, it is just an internal identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation number is not set by `\label`, but instead by the `equation` environment. To reference something, you need to have a label set in the document that is visible to the readers. This is done by `equation`, but not by `\[`...`\]`. So, yes, you need `equation` (or some other display math environment that also enumerates):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  V^{m \times n} = G^{m \times 3p} P^{3p \times n}
  \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
Where `$m$' represents the number of channels, `$n$' time samples considered, and
`$p$' the number of dipoles considered. See~\eqref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

Additional notes:

- No blank lines around the `equation` environment as it forms part of the paragraph structure, and affects the indentation of subsequent paragraphs (but this may be personal preference).
- Using a backtick and apostrophe as a pair for quoting.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. But when equation is under a section, section number is used for referencing instead of (1) by latex.

Comment: @WupadrastaSantosh: You need to place `\label` *inside* the `equation` environment.

Comment: Still, equation is labelled as (2.1), section numbering but not as (1).

Comment: @WupadrastaSantosh: Can you supply a small document that replicates this (unbelievable) behaviour? Something that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` has (say) two sections and an `equation` environment with a `\label` in it that I can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see what you're seeing? Perhaps use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: I have included in the code which behaves unbelievably, in the question..

Comment: @WupadrastaSantosh: Okay, I see what's going on here. The labelling of the equation under `report` is set to be `\thechapter.\arabic{equation}`, meaning it *always* prepends the equation number with the chapter counter (separated by a `.`). It just so happens that it *seems* the same as the section number, because the section number is formatted as `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`. Note the similarities. If you just want consecutive numbering of the equations (that doesn't restart every `\chapter`), then add `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` to your preamble.

Comment: Wow, it works.. Please explain how `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` solves the problem in your answer.

Comment: @WupadrastaSantosh: [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)` provides the functionality to `ch`a`ng`e the numbering of `c`ou`nt`e`r`s. Specifically, in this example it allows us to *remove* the counting of `equation` inside `chapter` via `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}`. This does two things: (1) Removes the `equation` counter from being reset with every `\chapter`, and (2) updates the way `\theequation` is displayed (by removing the prepended `\thechapter.`).